# Vuejs Reactivity on Set Value

Tags: vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a custom table with actions via a modal popup that set values on Rows. Things are mostly working great (Updates to Foo and Bar get sent to the backend and are set in a database, reload of the page pulls the data from the database and shows foo/bar were correctly set). The only not-great part is on setting of Foo, the value in the table does not get updated. Bar gets updated/is reactive. (the template uses foo.name and bar.id). Does anyone have any ideas on how to get Foo to update in the table? I've changed the moustache template to use {{ foo.id }} and it updates, but I need foo.name.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <c-dialog
      v-if="foo_modal"
      title="Set Foo"
      :actions="foo_modal_options.actions"
      @cancel="foo_modal = null">
      <slot>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Foo:</label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="foo_modal.thing.foo.id">
            <option v-for="foo in foos" :key="foo.id" :value="foo.id">{{ foo.name }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </slot>
    </c-dialog>
    <c-dialog
      v-if="bar_modal"
      title="Set Rod/Stick"
      :actions="bar_modal_options.actions"
      @cancel="bar_modal = null">
      <slot>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Rod:</label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="bar_modal.thing.rod.id">
            <option v-for="bar in bars" :key="bar.id" :value="bar.id" v-if="bar.type === 'rod'">{{ bar.id }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Stick:</label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="bar_modal.thing.stick.id">
            <option v-for="bar in bars" :key="bar.id" :value="bar.id" v-if="bar.type === 'stick'">{{ bar.id }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </slot>
    </c-dialog>

    <c-table-paginated
      class="c-table-clickable"
      :rows="grid.data"
      :columns="grid.columns"
      :actions="grid.actions"
      :key="componentKey">
    </c-table-paginated>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import fooModal from '../../components/fooModal.vue';
    import barModal from '../../components/barModal.vue';
    import CTablePaginated from "../../components/custom/cTable/cTablePaginated";
    import cTooltip from '../../components/custom/cTooltip/cTooltip.vue';
    import cDialog from '../../components/custom/cDialog/cDialog.vue';
    import moment from 'moment';

    export default {
        components: { CTablePaginated, cTooltip, cDialog },
        methods: {
            loadData() {
                let that = this;
                that.$http.get('/things', { params: that.param || {} })
                    .then(function (things) {
                        that.things = things.data;
                        that.grid.data = that.things;
                    });
            },
            setBar(thing_id, options, cb) {
                let that = this;
                this.$http.patch(`/things/${thing_id}`, { rod_id: options.rod, stick_id: options.stick })
                    .then(function () {
                        cb();
                    });
            },
            setFoo(thing_id, options, cb) {
                let that = this;
                this.$http.patch(`/things/${thing_id}`, { foo_id: options.foo_id })
                    .then(function () {
                        cb();
                    })
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                componentKey: 0,
                things: null,
                foos: [],
                bars: [],
                foo_modal: null,
                foo_modal_options: {
                    actions: [
                        {
                            label: "Save",
                            class: "btn-primary",
                            action: (function (ctx) {
                                return function () {
                                    const thing = ctx.foo_modal.thing;
                                    const options = {
                                        foo_id: thing.foo.id,
                                    };
                                    ctx.setFoo(thing.id, options, function () {
                                        ctx.foo_modal = null;
                                    });
                                }
                            })(this)
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Cancel",
                            action: (function (ctx) {
                                return function () {
                                    ctx.foo_modal = null;
                                }
                            })(this)
                        }
                    ]
                },
                bar_modal: null,
                bar_modal_options: {
                    actions: [
                        {
                            label: "Save",
                            class: "btn-primary",
                            action: (function (ctx) {
                                return function () {
                                    const thing = ctx.bar_modal.thing;
                                    const options = {
                                        rod: thing.rod.id,
                                        stick: thing.stick.id
                                    };
                                    ctx.setBar(thing.id, options, function () {
                                        ctx.bar_modal = null;
                                    });
                                }
                            })(this)
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Cancel",
                            action: (function (ctx) {
                                return function () {
                                    ctx.bar_modal = null;
                                }
                            })(this)
                        }
                    ]
                },
                grid: {
                    data: [],
                    columns: [
                        {
                            label: "Foo",
                            value: function (row) {
                                if (!row.foo) return "No foo set";
                                return `${row.foo.name }`;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Rod/Stick",
                            value: function (row) {
                                if (!row.rod && !row.stick) return "No rod/stick set";
                                if (!row.rod) return `No rod set/${row.stick.id}`;
                                if (!row.stick) return `${row.rod.id}/no stick set`;
                                return `${row.rod.id}/${row.stick.id}`;
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    actions: [
                        {
                            label: "Set Foo",
                            visible: function (thing) {
                                return !thing.active;
                            },
                            action: (function (ctx) {
                                return function (thing) {
                                    if (!thing.foo) thing.foo = {};
                                    ctx.foo_modal = {
                                        thing: thing
                                    };
                                }
                            })(this)
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Set Bar",
                            visible: function (thing) {
                                return !thing.active;
                            },
                            action: (function (ctx) {
                                return function (thing) {
                                    if (!thing.rod) thing.rod = {};
                                    if (!thing.stick) thing.stick = {};
                                    ctx.bar_modal = {
                                        thing: thing
                                    };
                                }
                            })(this)
                        },
                    ],
                }
            };
        },
        props: {
            title: {
                type: String
            },
            param: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            events: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        },
        created() {
            let that = this;
            this.loadData();
            this.$http.get('/bars')
                .then(function (bars) {
                    that.bars = bars.data;
                });
            this.$http.get('/foos')
                .then(function (foos) {
                    that.foos = foos.data;
                });
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. We're going to struggle without a complete, minimal test case: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. My only suggestion is to try logging `foo` to the console to check whether the `name` property is reactive. It's usually pretty easy to tell which properties are reactive, they have getters so the browser won't evaluate them until you click on them individually. Contrast that with the properties of a normal (non-reactive) object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities you can try both if any one of them can help you.

1. You can set value by using Vuejs this.$set method for deep reactivity. [Click here.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)
2. You can use this.$nextTick(()=>{ // set your variable here }). [Click here.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)